# $R_k=\min\{n\geq R_{k-1}:X_n\geq X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1} \}$ is a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I found this problem in a test but I don´t know how to solve it:

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be independent random variables with distribution function $F$. Define $R_1=1$, and $R_k=\min\{n\geq R_{k-1}:X_n\geq X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1} \}$. Show that $(R_k)_{k\geq 1}$ is a Markov Chain.

Any ideas?

Comment: Given the current state $R_k$, the next-state value $R_{k+1}$ is conditionally independent of the values $R_1, ..., R_{k-1}$. We don't care what these values are to simulate the process forward in time.

Answer (score 1):

For any positive integers $i,j$, we have that
$$
\mathbb P(R_{k+1} = j \mid R_k = i, R_{k-1}, R_{k-2},\ldots, R_1) = \mathbb P(R_{k+1}=j\mid R_k=i),
$$
since $R_k$ is $\sigma(X_i, X_{i+1},\ldots X_j)$-measurable and hence is independent of $\sigma(R_1,R_2,\ldots,R_{i-1})$. It follows that $\{R_k:k=1,2,\ldots\}$ is a Markov chain.

Comment: Why $R_k$ is $\sigma(X_i, X_{i+1},\ldots X_j)$-measurable?

Comment: Because the value of $R_k$ is fully determined by the values of $X_i,X_{i+1},\ldots,X_j$. It matters not what the values of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{i-1}$ are, nor what the values of $X_{j+1}, X_{j+2},\ldots$ are.

Comment: By construction, $X_{R_{k-1}}=max\left\lbrace X_j: j\leq R_{k-1}\right\rbrace$, and you're looking at $R_k=min \lbrace n\geq R_{k-1} : X_n\geq X_1,\dots, X_{n-1} \rbrace = min \lbrace n\geq R_{k-1} : X_n = max\lbrace X_j : j\leq n\rbrace \rbrace$. Then $X_{R_k}$ will be the cumulant maximum of the $X_n$ as soon as it is greater than $X_{R_{k-1}}$, and thus the value of $R_{k-1}$ contains all the information from the past and $(R_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Markov chain.